# Follow the MS tutorial, but see the error [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Connection not open ODBC Error in SQLDisconnect

Tags: sql-server, r, t-sql

Using the following Microsoft SQL Server R Machine Learning link, I am able to execute till step 2 and everything goes fine:

https://microsoft.github.io/sql-ml-tutorials/R/customerclustering/step/3.html

But when I try to deploy the ML model in SQL SERVER 2017, I will always see the following issues:

> Msg 39004, Level 16, State 20, Line 122 A 'R' script error occurred
>   during execution of 'sp_execute_external_script' with HRESULT
>   0x80004004. Msg 39019, Level 16, State 2, Line 122 An external script
>   error occurred:
>
> [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Login failed for user
>   'ASUS\MSSQLSERVER01'.
>
> Could not open data source. Error in doTryCatch(return(expr), name,
>   parentenv, handler) :    Could not open data source. Calls: source ...
>   tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> doTryCatch -> .Call
>
> Error in execution.  Check the output for more information. Error in
>   eval(expr, envir, enclos) :    Error in execution.  Check the output
>   for more information. Calls: source -> withVisible -> eval -> eval ->
>   .Call Execution halted
>
> STDOUT message(s) from external script:
>
> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Connection not open
>
> ODBC Error in SQLDisconnect

My codes are shown below:

```sql
USE [tpcxbb_1gb]
DROP PROC IF EXISTS generate_customer_return_clusters;
GO
CREATE procedure [dbo].[generate_customer_return_clusters]
AS
/*
  This procedure uses R to classify customers into different groups based on their
  purchase & return history.
*/

BEGIN
    DECLARE @duration FLOAT
    , @instance_name NVARCHAR(100) = @@SERVERNAME
    , @database_name NVARCHAR(128) = db_name()
-- Input query to generate the purchase history & return metrics
    , @input_query NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'
SELECT
  ss_customer_sk AS customer,
  round(CASE WHEN ((orders_count = 0) OR (returns_count IS NULL) OR (orders_count IS NULL) OR ((returns_count / orders_count) IS NULL) ) THEN 0.0 ELSE (cast(returns_count as nchar(10)) / orders_count) END, 7) AS orderRatio,
  round(CASE WHEN ((orders_items = 0) OR(returns_items IS NULL) OR (orders_items IS NULL) OR ((returns_items / orders_items) IS NULL) ) THEN 0.0 ELSE (cast(returns_items as nchar(10)) / orders_items) END, 7) AS itemsRatio,
  round(CASE WHEN ((orders_money = 0) OR (returns_money IS NULL) OR (orders_money IS NULL) OR ((returns_money / orders_money) IS NULL) ) THEN 0.0 ELSE (cast(returns_money as nchar(10)) / orders_money) END, 7) AS monetaryRatio,
  round(CASE WHEN ( returns_count IS NULL                                                                        ) THEN 0.0 ELSE  returns_count                 END, 0) AS frequency

FROM
  (
    SELECT
      ss_customer_sk,
      -- return order ratio
      COUNT(distinct(ss_ticket_number)) AS orders_count,
      -- return ss_item_sk ratio
      COUNT(ss_item_sk) AS orders_items,
      -- return monetary amount ratio
      SUM( ss_net_paid ) AS orders_money
    FROM store_sales s
    GROUP BY ss_customer_sk
  ) orders
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (
    SELECT
      sr_customer_sk,
      -- return order ratio
      count(distinct(sr_ticket_number)) as returns_count,
      -- return ss_item_sk ratio
      COUNT(sr_item_sk) as returns_items,
      -- return monetary amount ratio
      SUM( sr_return_amt ) AS returns_money
    FROM store_returns
    GROUP BY sr_customer_sk
  ) returned ON ss_customer_sk=sr_customer_sk
 '
EXEC sp_execute_external_script
      @language = N'R'
    , @script = N'
# Define the connection string
connStr <- paste("Driver=SQL Server;Server=", instance_name, ";Database=", database_name, ";Trusted_Connection=true;" , sep="" );


# Input customer data that needs to be classified. This is the result we get from our query
customer_returns <- RxSqlServerData(sqlQuery = input_query,
                                    colClasses = c(customer = "numeric", orderRatio = "numeric", itemsRatio = "numeric", monetaryRatio = "numeric", frequency = "numeric"),
                                    connectionString = connStr);

# Output table to hold the customer cluster mappings
return_cluster = RxSqlServerData(table = "customer_return_clusters", connectionString = connStr);

# set.seed for random number generator for predicatability
set.seed(10);

# generate clusters using rxKmeans and output clusters to a table called "customer_return_clusters".
clust <- rxKmeans( ~ orderRatio + itemsRatio + monetaryRatio + frequency, customer_returns, numClusters = 4
                    , outFile = return_cluster, outColName = "cluster", writeModelVars = TRUE , extraVarsToWrite = c("customer"), overwrite = TRUE);
'
    , @input_data_1 = N''
    , @params = N'@instance_name nvarchar(100), @database_name nvarchar(128), @input_query nvarchar(max), @duration float OUTPUT'
    , @instance_name = @instance_name
    , @database_name = @database_name
    , @input_query = @input_query
    , @duration = @duration OUTPUT;
END;

GO

-- Perform clustering in SQL Server
-- We are now going to execute the stored procedure in SQL Server to perform the clustering
-- Empty table of the results before running the stored procedure
TRUNCATE TABLE customer_return_clusters;
--Execute the clustering. This will load the table customer_return_clusters with cluster mappings
EXEC [dbo].[generate_customer_return_clusters];
```

The error will occur at the last line.

I suspect the issue is with the connection constr line which is:

```r
connStr <- paste("Driver=SQL Server;Server=", instance_name, ";Database=", database_name, ";Trusted_Connection=true;" , sep="" );
```

I checked and remove the unnecessary space, but it does not work.

Can any one help me to solve the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

sp_execute_external_script runs R script under a worker account and to get Windows Authentication to work in this scenario, you would need to [Enable implied authentication for the Launchpad account group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/r/set-up-sql-server-r-services-in-database#bkmk_FollowUp)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server}`.

For me it was throwing this error:

> error for Driver={SQL Server}

Answer (score 0):

For me solution was to add SQLRUserGroup as db_owner for the database in question, you can follow:
http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/r-library-rodbc-script-to-connect-sql-server-database.aspx
Go to the last section

Hope it helps, I was about to give up on this last step

Best